# Does Blitz++ use BLAS routines when it is possible and appropriate to

Tags: c++, blas, blitz++

I know that Blitz++ gets its performance plus by extensive usage of expression templates and template metaprogramms. But at some point you can't get more out of your code by using these techniques - you have to multiply and sum some floats up. At this point you can get a final performance kick by using the highly optimized (especially for special architectures) BLAS routines. Does the current implementation of Blitz++ use BLAS routines whenever it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only for benchmarks you must specify it when you configure blitz++:

```
./configure -with-blas=...
```

Blitz does  not use Blas routines.

Comment: do you have any citing sources for this?

Comment: Alas! This sole appearance of BLAS on the entire Blitz++ homepage recommends your claim...